# How to force android launcher using my new icon

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have an app and I have changed its launcher icon recently. But for some devices, such as MIUI devices, the icon display in launcher is still the old one.

I think there must be some cache here.

How can I force the android os to display my new icon?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006447/why-my-app-icon-is-not-updated-in-miui-or-vivo-launcher/52992510#52992510

Answer (score 0):

Look for this on your manifest android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" then change the ic_launcher to the name of your icon which is on your @drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to change the icon. My problem is that, some devices display the new icon while some device display the old one.

Comment: that might b onother issue ....but you should check you all the folder ..i think you have backup of your old icon in you ..hdp,mdpi or anything first check it

Comment: I am sure it is not a dpi problem. I have clear all the old icon resources from my app.

Comment: sorry bro dont know but this is the way you can chane you app icon

Answer (score 0):

You can change your new icon name from `ic_launcher`(if it is your old icon name) to some other name.

Comment: I have renamed `ic_launcher` to `ic`... but ... it does't work.