# Why my app icon is not updated in MIUI or vivo launcher?

Tags: android, icons

I change my app icon in my app,when I update my app into mi or vivo phone, the icon in the launcher is not updated, even i restart it or change themes.

Comment: this is miui bug,not relevant to out app developers,so don't  care about this too much.

Comment: Yeah,But it may have a bad effect on user experience.

Comment: yes,I commit this bug to miui before,but no response and no change...

Comment: @starkshang can you provide the url of your pull request for this fix. thanks

Comment: @jasonfungsing,I didn't solve this problem,I just figure out that it's a miui bug and I have commit this bug to miui developers.This bug just influence our developer,not to normal users.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by a crappy theme manager. Just change the theme, or if the phone is rooted, search for your package name under /data and delete the cached files.
There's not much you can do if this happens on a user's device.